# Freeze problem during widgets update Android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm developing ad turn by turn navigation app using Android.Now from a little of time, i noted that sometimes my app is freezing during navigation.Actually i'm using MapBox like routing provider and i update the widget during navigation in te following way:

In MapActivity when the map is ready i invoke a method

```
public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    //...code
    startLocationService();
    //..code
}
```

In startLocationService i'm using a timer to schedule a timerTask

```
private void startLocationService() {
    //...code
    locationTimer.schedule(new LocationTimerTask(), 1000, 1000);
    //...code
}
```

LocationTimetask

```
private class LocationTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            try {
                onPositionMoved(currentLocation);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i(LOGTAG, " Generic error on timer task ", ex);
            }
        }
}


private void onPositionMoved(Location currentLocation) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            //Some graphical updates
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.someId)).setText("Some text");
        });
}
```

I did some tests about this and seems that this graphical updates freeze tha app. Is this the correct way to update graphical widgets?

Any suggestions about this?